# Getting issue in reading query string in php

Tags: php, get, query-string

I've url as following format

```
http://domain.com/redirect?url=http://thirdpartydomain.com?aff_id=4234324&url=http://storesite.com/list/page/1
```

Here I want to get the value of first url key i,e.

```
http://thirdpartydomain.com?aff_id=4234324&url=http://storesite.com/list/page/1
```

What's best to get this,

I've tried suggested methods over SO but none of them worked me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$UrlYouNeed = substr($originalURL, strpos($originalURL, "=") + 1);
```

Comment: Maybe `$data` and `$originalURL` should be the same, rigth?

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_string="http://domain.com/redirect?url=http://thirdpartydomain.com?aff_id=4234324&url=http://storesite.com/list/page/1";

$your_string_explode=explode("http://",$your_string);

echo $your_string_explode[1];
```